# Plotting graph using androidplot for continuous incoming data

Tags: android, androidplot

I am plotting a graph with Dual Scale with values coming constantly from a device. I load the incoming values in two Array Lists and receive it in another activity which plots the graph. I am able to draw the graph now in a separate activity. Now, I would like to draw the graph in a separate fragment of main activity with new incoming values dynamically. My question is how to constantly draw the graph with new updated Array Lists. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the Dynamic XY Plot found [here](http://androidplot.com/docs/a-dynamic-xy-plot/)